# In FB Graph API 2.3 search event with place field

Tags: facebook-graph-api

In FB Graph API 2.3 the place field replaced the location and venue fields in the event node. However when using the search feature `(v2.3/search?q=*&type=event&fields=name,description,place)` if you request the place field an error is returned:

```
(#100) Unknown fields: place
```

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Get event ids from search endpoint, and then look up event details separately …? (Can be done using batch requests, if you don’t want to do it for each result event individually.)

Comment: That is a good suggestion @sgp but ideally I would like to have the place info available from the first search request. Especially since Facebook documentation states that the place field is now part of the event node. Maybe this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `venue` instead of `place`

```
v2.3/search?q=*&type=event&fields=name,description,venue
```

Visit 
http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Graph:Event for more fields.

Good luck